# WSO2 MDM license

Tags: wso2

can anyone use WSO2 MDM/EMM without the license as it is open source (Apache license version 2.0 2014)? I think WSO2 charge for support, not for software price so if someone doesn't require support from WSO2. So can they use free of charge legally?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the WSO2 software are free of charge. You can use it as you want. You can modify them as you require.

Comment: Does WSO2 send APK to android client or wso2 install apk to android phone without user interference? can anyone send any file to multiple android devices/clients sd card or internal storage simultaneously using wso2?

Comment: WSO2 IoT server can install applications to devices which are enrolled with the server. And File sharing feature is currently under development which will be available on 3.2.0 release.